# Why does my washing machine trip the GFCI breaker?

Tags: washing-machine

My Samsung washer WA52M7750AV/A4 occasionally pops the GFCI breaker. This a new home not quite a year old. The only item on the breaker is the washer.It always completes the wash cycle and the breaker pops maybe twice a month when I push power on to start another load. I think the breaker is to sensitive.. I have had this washer for about 5 months. The old washer never had this issue.. Thoughts and recommendations please..

Comment: Are the plumbing and drain pipes all rubber?

Answer (score 1):

#### Just doing what it is supposed to do!

A GFCI **needs** to be very sensitive to do its job. My guess is you've got some moisture getting into the controls and causing an intermittent ground fault. Which is **exactly** what the GFCI is supposed to do.

Since it is only 5 months old, I recommend talking to Samsung about a warranty repair. You might get "nowhere", but you might find that they have had other problems - perhaps bad gaskets or something allowing water to get where it shouldn't.

If you can't get any warranty (a.k.a. free) help from Samsung, then I would see if there is any way to seal the control panel better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that will be happening more and more now with newer washing machines and the newer requirements for them to be on GFCIs. Newer designs of washers are now using variable speed electronic motor controls inside, rather than the old simpler plain induction motors and gear boxes. The Variable Speed Drives that are inside are notoriously difficult to keep GFCIs from holding in consistently, because they create a lot of what is called "Common Mode Electrical Noise", which the GFCI circuitry sometimes interprets as leakage to ground.

One simple thing you can do is to double check ALL of the grounding (green) wires in/on the washing machine frame, make sure nothing is loose or corroded. If that doesn't help your choices are to live with it, or try installing different brands of GFCIs, because this issue seems to follow some brands more than others. If your breaker is Square D, that's one that is notorious for this issue. You can't usually install another brand of breaker in a Square D panel though, but the other option is to use a standard breaker, then put in a GFCI receptacle at the outlet. Then if that receptacle nuisance trips, keep changing brands until you find one that doesn't.

Comment: Switching brands of GFCI over and over looking for a non-oversensitive one seems like the definiton of insanity.  After one change, the chance approaches nil that *both* were oversensitive... And the exercise has become a hope to find a weak or defective one.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but this issue; VFD and ECMs (Electronically Commutated Motors) in appliances and swimming pools causing GFCIs to nuisance trip is getting to be so common that some equipment manufacturers have taken to listing which brands of GFCIs work with their equipment and tie their warranties to you having to use one of those.

Comment: That's rather useful info, and would be a good thing to be more specific about in your answer proper.  Indeed if your washer requires brand X GFCI and that's not your panel make, a GFCI deadfront or receptacle will be the only option. The fact that 99.9% of all GFCI+receptacle devices are 2-socket might put you in dutch with the "dedicated circuit" rules if that requires 1 socket on the only receptacle. GFCI+receptacle+switch combo units have 1 socket.

Comment: I don't doubt this is the problem *some* of the time. But in this particular case, the cycle finishes fine and it is at the start of a **new** cycle that the problem happens. Most washing machines fill first and then start the motor, so I am skeptical that a motor/GFCI interaction would result in the reported problem, plus it should then happen more frequently. The fact that it happens after a cycle makes me think moisture getting in and then "settling" after the cycle is finished. But that is just a guess.